# Bi-Lipschitz maps and identity

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, projection

Let $n,m$ be positive integers and consider a bi-Lipschitz linear map $L:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ where $d\leq n$ and $\mathbb{R}^d$ is viewed as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Is it possible to bound the distance:
$$
\sup_{x\in [0,1]^n}\,\|x-L(x)\|
$$
in terms of the (bi)-Lipschitz constants of $L$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k$ is the Lipschitz constant of $L$, then for any $x$, $\|L(x)\|\leqslant k\|x\|$. The triangle inequality thus yields
$$
\|x-L(x)\| \leqslant \|x\|+ \|L(x)\| \leqslant (1+k)\|x\|
$$

This bound is sharp since for $L(x) = -x$, it holds that
$$
\|x-L(x)\| = 2\|x\|
$$

Comment: I spoke too soon.  $L_t$ is not linear so its not an example of what I'm looking for.  But I guess $L_t:x \mapsto |t| x$ would have worked since $|x-L_t(x)| = (1-|t|)|x|$.  In this case, there is a clear upper-bound of $1-Lip(L_t)$ so I'm again wondering my question.

Comment: I didn't see you required for $L$ to be linear.

Comment: @TomTheQuant Please see my edited answer, which is positive because of the triangle inequality

Comment: Interesting, so $(1+Lip(L))$ is a generic (possibly tight I think) bound?

Comment: @TomTheQuant Please see the new edit, showing that the bound is sharp